# Neo4j querying and aggregation across multiple instances

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am planning to use neo4j for an event management system.  The involved entities are events, places, persons, organizations, so and so forth.  But inorder to keep each org data separate I plan to create separate DB instance for each org.  Becoz of this separation of Database instances, the 'Place' nodes are likely to get repeated in these mutliple db instances.

So, now, is it possible to aggregate for events based on `Place` nodes from all db instances?  Or is it that I have to build my own custom aggregation like map-reduce?

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j 4.0, if you have a license for enterprise edition, you can leverage [Neo4j Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/fabric/introduction/), which should allow you to do exactly this: connect to a proxy instance, which must be [configured](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/fabric/configuration/) to see other running db instances (which may be running on the same Neo4j dbms as the proxy instance, or which could instead be running on separate servers/clusters).

Then you can [query across](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/fabric/queries/) the graphs, aggregating and working with the result set across them as needed.